# Swift - Transitions to another View Controller (not popup)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, segue

I've been trying to link a button to a View Controller, and it works, but it keeps appearing as a popup! I don't want a popup, I want a full screen with a back button on the top.

I've looked at videos and everyone else holds ctrl + drags, but when I do that it still makes it a pop up.

Help! Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe you are using segues. You can try the segue types to change the transitions 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/resource_management/customizing_the_behavior_of_segue-based_presentations?language=objc

Have a look at this

Comment: You *probably* want to use a `UINavigationController` -- that handles the display and functionality of the Back button automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Go - Storyboard and check controller Properties as in picture set fullscreen

Transition-style = anyType

Presentation - fullScreen